# How to get current page item inside uiReturnFieldEditorValues pipeline

Tags: experience-editor

I have an EditFrame on a component and I need to make some changes on some fields, and it depends on some factors.
I catch the events when the edit frame fields are saved like on this blogpost: https://blog.trivident.com/automatically-refresh-page-in-sitecore-experience-editor-after-updating-a-component/ but I am not able to get current page item inside the processor :
**ReturnFieldEditorValues.SetValues**

Sitecore.Context.Item show me FieldEditor value:

[image]

I tried few others things but I couldn't find a way to get the current page item.

Comment: Did  you try `GetViewStateString("ItemID")`?

Comment: in the class ReturnFieldEditorValues.SetValues I don't have access to GetViewStateString, looks like this method is part of the Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Component and all the classes which inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, that's not really possible.

When you open an iframe, an url like `/sitecore/shell/applications/field editor.aspx?mo=mini&hdl=BC6886B8396B47CBB3345D82B6501C47}` is executed and it loads a modal with editor for fields of the item passed to edit frame.

As far as I'm aware, the request doesn't have any information about the original page, it only has information about the item passed to iframe.

And what is more, you cannot even check url referrer, as ReturnFieldEditorValues is called in second request, when you close the modal.

The only idea I have is adapting the code which opens `field editor.aspx` url to include page item id there as well.